# Guid matching between computers and systems

Tags: c#

I'll be doing a database data export into another database and the column of the table in the database have GUID as its identification. For instance, if I run the first time on 10,000 records and do another 10,000 records insert on top of the 10 thousand that were there (in total there will be 20,000 records) is there a chance that there would be a similar GUID in the 20,000 because it has been imported separately? I'm just thinking that if you import 100 thousand records by 10,000 each there is a chance that there will be duplicate GUIDs because the GUID generator doesn't know about the previous GUIDs it generated?

Comment: GUID = Globally Unique IDentifier

Comment: It is very very very unlikely.  That's the whole point of GUID.

Comment: [related link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fericlippert%2Farchive%2F2012%2F04%2F24%2Fguid-guide-part-one.aspx&ei=nwhiUMafFai00QHUtIHoDA&usg=AFQjCNEDbaDAVdgPIj-Alv4CYfUuKgAPBw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is guaranteed to be unique throughout the entire world and you will never get collisions unless the algorithm used to generate them is flawed (hopefully the database GUID generation algorithm that you are using is reliable). That's the whole point of a GUID. Well purists might say that technically there's a chance that you get collisions but this chance is purely academical, no practical.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, yes, this is true. But _technically_ it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, OK it's possible on paper, but for practical applications you could consider that this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

GUIDS are unique to their time and place of generation.  If you have duplicate GUIDs, at some point in the past, one has been copied from the other(or someone is generating them incorrectly)